# Magento Transactional Email config: best practice

Tags: email, magento, transactional

Every time I set up a Magento store I must spend an entire day setting up the stupid transactional emails since they are so weak by default.

Half of that time is spent just loading the templates into the backend and clicking around with Magento's user interface...

1. Is there a straight forward method to load all the emails in one sql statement or similar?
2. Have any of you found a way to quickly edit all the templates outside of Magento?
3. Any comments on the [email templates adapter](http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/email-template-adapter.html) extension (or similar)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please read about [Magento Setup Resources](http://www.magentocommerce.com/knowledge-base/entry/magento-for-dev-part-6-magento-setup-resources)

You can then update your email content/configuration using update scripts in dedicated module, for ex.:

`app/code/local/{project_prefix}/ConfigurationEmail`

Comment: Didn't know about this as I have never developed a module... mostly I do configuration and design. You and @benmarks are saying the same thing it seems. Thanks for the link.

Answer (score 1):

1. Magento allows you to run update scripts, so you could export the initial setup work and create an EmailSetup module. Note that you would also want to set the appropriate config data to link transactions with the DB emails.
2. We've made some shell scripts to make regular changes, many of which were obviated by changes which Magento made.
3. Not familiar.

Answer (score 0):

You should try the [Transactional Email extension](http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/comfirm-alphamail-9080.html) from Comfirm.

It makes handling transactional email in Magento a lot easier.